# Crystal report: Unable to connect: incorrect log on parameters

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, crystal-reports

This is the code of Crystal Report:

```
    ReportDocument reportDocument = new ReportDocument();
    reportDocument.Load(Server.MapPath(ReportName + ".rpt"));
    reportDocument.SetParameterValue("@userid", Convert.ToInt64(5));
    reportDocument.SetParameterValue("@Reportname", ReportName);
    reportDocument.SetParameterValue("@SessionId", Session.SessionID.ToString());
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportDocument;
    reportDocument.SetDatabaseLogon("sa", "Password1", "192.168.0.245", "databaseName", true);
```

It is saying "Unable to connect: incorrect log on parameters." although the login information is correct.

If I set the value to  "reportDocument.SetDatabaseLogon("sa", "Password1", "192.168.0.240", "databaseName", true);" it is working fine which is the login information was given during the designing the Crystal Report.

Answer (score 1):

Can try this and see if it helps?

```
       ConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo
                                            {
                                                UserID = user, 
                                                Password = pwd, 
                                                ServerName = server, 
                                                DatabaseName = db
                                            };
        TableLogOnInfo tableLogOnInfo = new TableLogOnInfo
                                            {
                                                ConnectionInfo = connectionInfo
                                            };
        foreach (Table table in reportDocument.Database.Tables)
        {
            table.ApplyLogOnInfo(tableLogOnInfo);
        }
```

Comment: It is now saying "Failed to open a rowset.". When I run the store procedure manually with the exact parameter values it showing the results. So the store procedure is returning the values. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem but has solved.

The problem is in odbc connection. Just install SQL native client to add connection in odbc.
Download link 
https://support.fotoware.com/hc/en-us/articles/208664385-Microsoft-SQL-Native-Client-fails-to-download-during-FotoWeb-setup